# Solving strange differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Whilst my knowledge of differential equations is somewhat limited, I was under the impression that the following was a valid equation to be solved yet it is unrecognised by wolfram alpha and I have no clue how to solve it:
$$dy = a\times x \times dx + b\times y$$
Is such a differential equation that contains differentials combined with variables valid in the sense that using differentials as terms as shown is mathematically acceptable and if so how can the equation be solved?

Comment: Assuming that the $\times$ indicates ordinary multiplication, your problem is the $by$ at the end.  Intuition (backed by the theory behind differential equations and notation) suggests that a differential $dy$ cannot be equal to another differential $ax\,dx$ plus a non-infinitesimal quantity like $by$.

Comment: If what you mean to write is $\frac{dy}{dx} = by+ax$, then that surely has a solution.  You can try it out on WA.

Comment: hmm that makes sense I'll look into the actual problem again to see if I've made a mistake in developing the equation. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianTung if you create an answer I'll accept it as on further look I've missed a very important infinitesimal component of the initial problem leading to an infinitesimal looking like a non-infinitesimal number.

Comment: @J-S So was Brian correct in that you meant to write $\frac{dy}{dx} = by+ax$? Given the correct equation I can give you the solution

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen No that was my result; it was not a typo. The problem lied not it mathematics or a mistype but rather in the assumptions I made concerning the domain of the problem (thermal physics) which I have corrected and thus found the correct differential equation which I was able to solve myself. Thanks anyway :)